# Atheros QCA9377 working at low speed

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I recently bought an ACER E5-573-50LX with an Atheros QCA9377 onboard.
Thanks to some posts I was able to get the device working, using [kvalo's software](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/).

Acessing my WIFI router I get low speeds, (1Mb/s or 6 Mb/s) and a low signal rating. With the same PC & windows,all is fine.

Any suggestions what I can do to solve this?

Edit: requested output can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23133645/

Comment: What kernel? What Ubuntu version?

Comment: I tried with : 1) Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4) 2) ubuntu 12.4 (standard kernel + backports) and now installed on 12.04 kernel 4.5.0-040500-generic, all same issue, card gets recognized, but working intermittent  and al low speed

Comment: I can report the same here, with Asus TP200SA. Currently using 4.4.0-36. Trying kernels 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8rc3, 4.8rc4, the problem gets worse!
I need to rfkill block and unblock every few seconds.

Comment: My wifi is 168c:0042 rev 30

Comment: May we see: `dmesg | grep ath` and also: `sudo iwlist scan` As the result will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hello, I added data on dmesg | grep ath and also: sudo iwlist scan on http://paste.ubuntu.com/23133645/

Comment: Related: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/faq/

Comment: I have the same issue, I've tested using 2 identical laptops one running windows 10, one Ubuntu 16.04 and using iperf3 on a hardwired server. Ubuntu Laptop gets roughly 10Mbps the Windows laptop gets 100Mbps. I've pinned the access point to only broadcast using N and to disable b/g.

Answer (score 2):

First the ath10k driver doesn't report the correct/real speed as indicated in [ath10k FAQ](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/faq). So the "Bit Rate" stay stuck at 1Mb/s.

Second there is a major performance issue with QCA9377 in Linux kernel 4.4 , I recommend to upgrade your kernel to 4.8 version.

Answer (score 2):

Had the low Wi-Fi speed under Ubuntu 20.10 on an Acer Aspire E 15 e5-575g-53s6 with the same QCA9377 network card. The latest kvalo's firmware is already supplied in the system.

However, *removing* the `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin` file and rebooting helped. The system works with the previous `firmware-5.bin` with perfect speed now.

Comment: Dear sir, you just saved the last piece of my sanity. After trying a dozen different things which didn't work, something as simple as removing `firmware-6.bin` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Research indicates that the information available on that interface is minimal however, It appears from your pastebin output that firmware is failing to load and no channel is getting configured. Since the QCA9377 supports it you might try `iw` which is a "new" nl80211 based CLI configuration utility for wireless devices. It supports all new drivers that have been added to the kernel recently. The old tool `iwconfing`, which uses Wireless Extensions interface, is deprecated and it's strongly recommended to switch to `iw` and nl80211.

You might start by insuring that there is no stronger signal than yours on the frequency/channel you intend to use (and if so pick a less crowded one) I've found the android app [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) useful in determining what the best channel to use in a specific area is. Having made this determination you can continue with configuring your router to that channel and then wireless as well with `iw` Documentation is available [here.](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw/)

You can get further useful information by getting station statistics against a peer

If you want to get specific statistics against a peer your station is communicating with you can use the following:

`sudo iw dev wlp3s0 station get <peer-MAC-address>`
In the case of a STA the above  would be the MAC address of your AP (router). Where wlp3s0 is your wireless device which matches to your pastebin output of `wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0`

You can use iw to specify specific Tx rates and Tx power as well which might be quite useful under the circumstances. I might also try turning off power saving for the interface. You can check it with  `iw dev wlp3s0 get power_save`

If it's on you can turn it off with `sudo iw dev wlp3s0 set power_save off`

Comment: It seems to me that this driver is already included in kernel 4.7.2 and/or 4.8rc4. I know that the latest linux-firmware .deb from Yakkety already comes with the latest firmware .bin files from the kvalo's git repository.

Comment: @UrkoM Changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try instaling your driver manually.

place it in your home and run these commands in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential

$ wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz

$ tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz

$ cd backports-20151120

$ make defconfig-ath10k

$ make

$ sudo make install
```

turn your Wi-Fi off when doing these steps. Use LAN or Tether android phone to PC
please let me know the result.

Comment: I don't recommend this. S/he already has a newer and presumably better developed driver.

Comment: It's just an option to reconfigure the Wi-Fi settings.  Because I have the same laptop and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i made this custom kernel for all debian based linux including ubuntu, i have added a patch to speedup ath10k driver responsible for QCA9377,(i have Lenovo S340)

https://github.com/psndna88/AGNi-xanmod_x86-64/releases

Comment: This sounds great, but how would this be installed?