# Ubuntu 18 Wifi very slow Qualcomm Atheros

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

```
sudo lshw -C network


*-network
       описание: Беспроводной интерфейс
       продукт: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       производитель: Qualcomm Atheros
       физический ID: 0
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:03:00.0
       логическое имя: wlp3s0
       версия: 31
       серийный №: e8:2a:44:f5:7a:03
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       конфигурация: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-34-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 ip=192.168.0.153 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ресурсы: IRQ:131 память:94000000-941fffff
```

Wifi speed 1 Mb/s (((

Comment: Please try to use English here as we are all not from same language. And I dont think slow internet is relevant problem here. better to conduct with the internet provider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atheros QCA9377 working at low speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768488/atheros-qca9377-working-at-low-speed)